# Definition of (or determine whether something is) a robust controller?

Tags: control

I am bit uncertain how I should interpret the definition of an robust controller.

As far I've understood, the closed loop system including the controller has to have a high gain for frequencies where disturbance appears, and decay at frequencies higher than the work area, or noise.  Both of these can be determined using a bode plot, thereby determining the robustness of my closed-loop system.

Answer (score 2):

In its [broadest sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_control), a controller is "robust" when it allows for bounded variations to its parameters – in other words, the controller continues to work as long as its parameters remain within a given bounded range. In the context of Bode work, this translates to high-gain feedback, but it's not necessarily true elsewhere – see for example the [H-infinity methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_infinity).

Comment: The variation to take into account for robustness is regarded also with the plant, not only the controller; especially the plant, I would rather say.